# Visual studio hotkey to go between different windows

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys

Is there a hotkey to switch between different windows? I know about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, which can be used to switch between active tabs, but I would like a way to switch between various windows created by visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a96fx0b9.aspx

See the section: Navigating Among Tool Windows in the IDE

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to the [above answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-move-around-in-the-visual-studio-ide?view=vs-2019#navigate-among-tool-windows-in-the-ide), you will find that "Navigate among files" and "Navigate among tool windows" have the same name: "Window.PreviousDocumentWindowNav"
I found that the way to switch is to press the left and right arrow keys when pressing "Ctrl+tab" to switch.